# How to add custom grammar in Sphinx4 for speech recognition in Java?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech, sphinx4

I am using `sphinx4 1.0 beta 6` to make a voice recognizer in Java. In sphinx4 there is demo sample called HelloWorld. That demo runs well without any problem. But it recognize only few words. I have to change its `hello.gram` file. If I add some extra words in that grammar file it doesn't work for those word. How can I add my own grammar file and load in HelloWorld sample? I have studied a lot on JSGFGrammar. But I couldn't understand. I am using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: After you add words to the grammar you need rebuild the sources. You also need to add words to the dictionary. It's better to use latest version sphinx4-5prealpha, not 1.0beta6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `helloworld.config.xml` file. In this xml file you have to change the location of the grammar file. Just find and make this line `<property value="resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/helloworld/" name="grammarLocation"/>` to `<property value="resource:/your/grammar/file/location" name="grammarLocation"/>`. And if you want to change the name of your grammar file hello.gram to ssomething else you have to change this line `<property value="your file name" name="grammarName"/>`

This should work.

Comment: question is that. After updating the hello.gram file means by adding new words in gram file, the program does load or recognize the added words in hello.gram file. How can I load it as well?